# split comma separated values to multiple rows

Tags: mysql, split

A single user having multiple tigs values in tigs column (Table 1 image). 
and want to show comma separated numeric value into row wise for every numeric value using mysql query? (Like Table 2).
[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN5Kl.png)
[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTR3K.png)

Comment: Please put some efforts in framing a question with **relevant and minimal sample data** showcasing your requirements, and **corresponding expected output**. Please read this link: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you need to display separately then why stored with comma separated. There is no MySQL function which explode values and join internally with table to produce Cartesian result.
If you take table join of tigs fields then it is possible.

Comment: i have a seperate table named: tigs where tigs informations are stored. and for every user we are assigning multiple tig codes, but now we want to show every tig seperately